# Cadillac CTS no compression bank 1

Tags: engine, cadillac

I was driving and my RPMs drop to 0. I have no compression on my right side of engine. I’ve done a test. Driver side is good. Car turns over but won’t start. When it drop to 0 I couldn’t accelerate. Just pulled over & stop engine. Wire harness? Time chain?

Comment: How many cylinders have no compression?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What engine do you have, and what year? You've measured the compression on each cylinder?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting compression on one side, I'd suggest part of the valve train has failed. The engine is a dual overhead cam (DOHC) setup. Each cylinder head's cams are actuated by a separate chain as well as the sprockets which contain the goodies for variable valve timing (VVT). If the chain on the one side or any part which actuates those cams has failed, you'd be getting zero compression on that side. The only way you can tell for sure is by taking that side valve cover off and verifying the movement of the cams. If this IS the case, you most likely have a toasted engine, as you're going to have bent valves on that side of the engine, as well as damage to the pistons (most likely).

Comment: What if the engine is non interference. Is it possible the chain just skip timing? Before I cut the car off I didn’t hear any metal to metal.

Comment: You most likely wouldn't hear metal on metal contact. Because it happens during the first couple revolutions of the engine ... it's still running and making engine noises. You most likely wouldn't hear them.

Comment: I can’t get the car started though. Even tried starter fluid through intake. Still no luck. I’m taking it to a dealership for diagnosis. I just think it’s weird to lose compression on all three cylinders at same time on the same side. Car has a chain for each side. I even thought about the distributor motor could fail.

Comment: If it only has three cylinders it ***can*** run off of, it's not going to. Plus, if the cams aren't spinning, the cam sensor isn't going to provide input, which means the ECU isn't going to know when to tell the ignition to fire. Everything you're saying is saying there's a cam or cams which are not spinning. And why are you trying to start it if there's even the smallest chance the cam chain is busted. You are only going to cause MORE DAMAGE.